# default username and password for Fedora 27 for Virtualbox

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, password

I downloaded Fedora 27 for Virtualbox (.box file) from this webpage https://app.vagrantup.com/fedora/boxes/27-atomic-host,
but cannot find the default username and password.
I tried username fedora with password fedora, passw0rd, and tried without a password but all failed.
Someone advise to set the default password myself but cannot find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default username and password for Vagrant boxes is `vagrant`/`vagrant` (`root` password is also `vagrant`) but you shouldn't need it, `vagrant up` inserts SSH key to the machine and you should use `vagrant ssh` to login to it without password.

Also Fedora 27 is no longer supported, its support ended in 2018, you should use latest version (33).

Comment: Username vagrant and password vagrant worked. I have to use it for some compatibility issue.